# npm init no me permite continuar

Tags: javascript, npm

al correr el comando **npm init** todo bien solo que en el paso de la version no me deja hacer nada ni cerrar la vantana de la terminal.

tengo instaldo como sistema operativo linux a **Antergos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**nodejs 8.1.0**

**npm 5.0.3**

Comment: Puede ser culpa de tu sistema, estas corriendo en linux, windows? podrias especificar bien cual es la descripcion de tu pc

Comment: Que raro... abre otra terminal y mata al proceso.

Comment: Tambien he usado npm@5 por mi parte, y no esta muy estable, te recomiendo esperar a los siguientes release

Comment: tengo instaldo como sistema operativo linux a Antergos

Comment: con npm 4 da el  mismo error

Comment: Por lo que se lee en este issue (Problema) en [git](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17126) es un problema ya conocido, creo que lo mejor es esperar a que se resuelva, yo uso actualmente la 3.10.10 y esta perfecta así que lo mejor es un downgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error es la versión de node.js, actualmente funciona en node.js v8.2.1